# Can I change a (Netflix) Hollow model schema's field inlining once it's in use?

Tags: netflix, netflix-hollow

I'm working on software that propagates, to a fleet of servers, a medium-sized data set that doesn't change very often. I'm using Netflix's [Hollow](http://hollow.how/) library to do it.

I've been thinking of the lifecycle of my application, and how it will grow and change over time. I've looked at the [notes on backwards compatibility](http://hollow.how/data-modeling/#maintaining-backwards-compatibility) in the Hollow docs, and I don't think my question is addressed there.

When tuning my model for speed and memory efficiency, I can foresee deciding that a field I was referencing by id would be better off [inlined](http://hollow.how/data-modeling/#inlined-vs-referenced-fields), or vice versa.

Is inlining backwards compatible? That is, if I have inlined a field:

```
@HollowInline String title;
```

and I determine that I'd be better served by making the field a reference instead, can I just remove the inline annotation?

```
String title;
```

Or, as seems more likely, will that break my clients?

My hypothesis is that the only safe way to change inlining status is to add a new field with the desired inlining status, migrate my producer and consumers to use it, and then remove the old one.

Comment: Gulp. The hollow SO tag referred to in the documentation doesn't exist: http://hollow.how/community/#stack-overflow

Comment: It looks like [the Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/Netflix/hollow) is the best place to be for Hollow how-to discussions.

Comment: I have created a PR on the GitHub repo letting them know about the tag change for the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a backwards *incompatible* change as you surmise. Given this schema:

`java
class A {
  int a1;
  @HollowInline Integer a2;
}`

Changing `int a1` to `Integer a1` and removing the `@HollowInline` annotation are equivalent. Changing an existing field from inline to reference or reference to inline is a breaking schema change.

A couple strategies can work around this:

**Strategy 1**

1. introduce a new field name; in your example you could call it `String titleRef` or `String titleV2`
2. populate `title` and `titleV2` with the same value
3. release a new client API
4. once all consuming apps/services have upgraded and switched to call `getTitleV2()` you can remove `title` from the schema and begin publishing data without it

**Strategy 2**

1. Given: you use a namespace or naming scheme (such as naming the path to your blobs a certain way and announcing your versions under a topic name)
2. make the breaking change to your schema
3. change or rev your namespace
4. stand up a new producer publishing and announcing to the new namespace running in parallel to the old producer
5. release a new client; consumers picking up this new client should be configured to use the new namespace (it could be baked in to a wrapper you release with the client, for instance)
6. once all consuming app/services are using new client with new namespace, retire old producer